# jquery validate dependency callback on "minvalue"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Is it possible to write a dependency callback for the minValue rule, such as you can with the required text?

I have 2 required fields -> Price Paid and Price Seen (for a rebate form). I tried to write something like this:

```
     minValue: function(element) {
          $("#PP_PriceSeen").val();
     }
```

if I try to set an alert or something, I do get the correct value, but it isnt being passed into the rule. Is this only allowed for the 'required' option?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code mean? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: it is used with the jquery Validation library here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easy enough to accomplish this with a custom validator rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod("minDependency", function (value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || ((parseInt(value, 10) || 0) >= (parseInt($(params).val(), 10) || 0));
}, "Please enter at least the minimum value");

$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        fieldName: {
            minDependency: "#min"
        }
    }
});
```

This defines a new rule `minDependency` that accepts a selector as a parameter. The selector's value is compared against the element under validation.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/wqSGE/

Answer (score 0):

The `val()` method is jQuery's default method. It returns value of element.

You might wanted to use `validate()` method of jQuery validation plugin. If you want to validate "minvalue" you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You can find full code of the example in [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength#length). You can also find other informations in this documentation.